# Convert given number to power in Java

Tags: java

I have a main function that calls another function and passes the given number as a parameter. In the other function, I want to break up the given number into sums of power. How can this be done?

My code looks like:

```
public static void main()
{
String hello=raisetopower(in.nextInt());
}

public String raisetopower(int n)
{
// do the logic
}
```

Explanation :

say if the number is 25: the function should return 5^2 + 0^2
and if it is 26: 5^2+1^2

Comment: This is really a question of mathematics rather than Java programming, please provide an algorithm for solving this problem.

Comment: @SanjeevSaha if it is 27 : 3^3+0^1

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the power given to `0` or `1`?

Comment: There is no 'convert given number to power' here. The question is in fact under-specified. *Presumably* you are really doing prime factorization, but it's anybody's guess really.

Comment: And on what basis should you add `0^2` or `0^1`? It's just zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found the solution of this problem over here : https://github.com/Widea/Interview-Questions/blob/master/Hard/Random/PowerNumbers.java

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Richard's comment that this more Mathematics than Java

The question needs more information to be able to provide code to assist, such as whether or not you consider a maximum base like 10 and whether or not all bases should be in the output even if they are to the power of 0 as your example is confusing:

> "say if the number is 25: the function should return 5^2 + 0^2 and if
>   it is 26: 5^2+1^2"

However with that in mind, hopefully this example will be able to assist

---

Assuming you do have a maximum base being considered, you could start from the highest base to the lowest and use logs

If the result of the log is greater than or equal to 1, then this value should be in the output, so subtract that value and continue on to the next base

Keep continuing until you hit a value of exactly 1 and that should be your end condition

E.g assuming a maximum base of 5 for this example with an input of 27

```
log5 27 = 2.04781858346
```

so we will have 5^2 in the output and subtract this from the input, you could use floor to extract the '2'

```
log4 2 = 0.5
```

less than one so not an integer power

```
log3 2 = 0.630929753571
```

less than one so not an integer power

```
log2 2 = 1
```

add to output as greater than or equal to 1 and terminate as it is exactly 1

If you're only displaying bases with powers greater than or equal to one (this was unclear), your output at this point would be:

```
27 = 25^2 + 2^1
```

You could use a `StringBuilder` or an ordered collection of custom objects holding your bases and powers to make it easier to generate the output

---

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for my above algorithm:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberToPowerConversion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxBaseToConsider = 5;
        System.out.println("Input number to convert: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = input.nextInt();
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Represented as powers: " + number + " = ");

        for(int base = maxBaseToConsider; base >= 1; base--){
            //Prevent division by 0 (log 1)
            double logResult = base > 1 ? Math.log(number) / Math.log(base) : 1;
            int floorResult = (int)Math.floor(logResult);
            if(number == 1 || logResult == 1.0){
                output.append(base + "^" + floorResult);
                number -= Math.pow(base, floorResult);
                if(number != 0){
                    //If the number couldn't be broken down completely, add the remainder to the output
                    output.append(" + " + number + "^1"); //To keep format consistent
                }
                break; //end condition reached
            }
            else if(floorResult >= 1){
                output.append(base + "^" + floorResult);
                number -= Math.pow(base, floorResult);
                if(number == 0){ break; }
                else{ output.append(" + "); }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
}
```

---

Example output:

```
Represented as powers: 27 = 5^2 + 2^1
Represented as powers: 77 = 5^2 + 4^2 + 3^3 + 2^3 + 1^1
Represented as powers: 234 = 5^3 + 4^3 + 3^3 + 2^4 + 1^1 + 1^1
Represented as powers: 99 = 5^2 + 4^3 + 3^2 + 2^0
Represented as powers: 1 = 5^0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Algorithm :
   i <- square root of n
   while n<1
     n <- n-square of i
     r <- r concatenate with i^2
     if n=0 r concatenate with i^0
     if n=1 r concatenate with i^1
     i <- square root of n
   return r
*/    

public static String raisetopower(int n){
    String raised="";
    int i=(int)Math.sqrt(n);

    while(n>1){
        n=n-(int)Math.pow(i,2);
        raised+=String.valueOf(i)+"^2+"; 

        if(n==0)
            raised+="0^2";
        if(n==1)
            raised+="1^2";
        i=(int)Math.sqrt(n);
    }
    return raised;
}
```

Comment: One squared is still one, and there are more powers in the question and comments than just 2.

Comment: Question is regarding squares, no other powers are required

Comment: There is no mention of squares in the question, or of 'no other powers required' either. OP specifies `3^3` as a solution in a comment.